# Python parse module search

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Using the python parse module.
I am searching within a string.
Searching for "AB Number" then multiple spaces then a number in the format 1-123456789.

so "AB Number        1-727288292920"

If i use this it finds it but its split over multiple matches:-

```
search('AB Number{:s}{:d}{:D}{:d}',plain_text_body)
```

If i use this it only matches the first digit and i cant work out why it wont match

```
search('AB Number{:s}{\d+\D\d+}',plain_text_body)
```

Also I think its possible to use regex outside of the pattern being captured but i cant make that work either for example - to catch multiple spaces should be:-

```
search('AB Number\s+{\d+\D\d+}',plain_text_body)
```

But it doesnt work.
Any idea?

Comment: `import re`, and then `re.findall(r'\bAB Number\s*\d-\d{12}(?!\d)', s)`?

Comment: So you don’t recommend the parse module?

Comment: If you need to *extract* texts matching your requirements, you may rely on `re`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it.

```
import re

pattern = r'^(AB Number).+(\d\-\d{1,})$'
text = 'AB Number sdf sfd  1-727288292920'

for m in re.match(pattern, text).groups(): 
    print(repr(m))
```

output

```
... 
'AB Number'
'1-727288292920'
```